# How to clear OpenFileDialog's history

Tags: vb.net

I have this code below. Here's what's happening and what I did:

1. Click the button and select a single photo.
2. Click again the button and select more than 10 images. A messagebox will pop up saying "Only 10 photos are needed". **My problem is that the messagebox is showing twice.**
3. When I clicked the button again and select more than 10 images again, the messagebox will show thrice.

Is there a way how to **clear* the openfiledialog so that the message box will only show once.

By the way, here's my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBrowse.Click
        'Limits the number of photos to 10
        AddHandler OpenFileDialog1.FileOk, Sub(s, ce)
                                               If OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Length > 10 Then
                                                   MsgBox("Only 10 photos are needed.")
                                                   ce.Cancel = True
                                               End If
                                           End Sub
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim images As String

            For Each images In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
                Dim pics As New PictureBox

                'Sets the properties of the picturebox in the TableLayoutPanel
                pics.Height = 120
                pics.Width = 120
                pics.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
                pics.Image = Image.FromFile(images)
                pics.Load(images)

                'Add every images uploaded using the OpenFileDialog
                TableLayoutPanelNitrogen.Controls.Add(pics)

                'Sets the course of action based on the number of controls within the TableLayoutPanel
                If TableLayoutPanelNitrogen.Controls.Count < 10 Then
                    Continue For
                ElseIf TableLayoutPanelNitrogen.Controls.Count = 10 Then
                    BtnBrowse.Enabled = False
                    Exit For
                ElseIf TableLayoutPanelNitrogen.Controls.Count > 10 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next images
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: That's because you keep calling AddHandler on the *same* object.  Do it only once.  Or do it the way I showed you, making it a local variable of the method.